# Posts of LinkedIn Company Page

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I like to display posts of `LinkedIn` `Company page` using JavaScript.

Currently I'm able to display only `Company Information` using JavaScript API reference.

```
function onLinkedInAuth() 
{
    IN.API.Raw("/companies/222180:(id,name,ticker,description,locations,company-type)").result(displayposts);
}
```

Is there any way to display top 5 posts of `Company page`?

Comment: does this has anything to do with c#?

Comment: no..I like to do with javascript only